# Preg_match and substr together

Tags: php, regex, string, validation

I have a string that I need to test to see if the characters after the [0] character (the very first) are numbers or not.

So example :

C is [0]

I then need to check if the remaining characters are only numbers meaning that after C we get :

12345678

making the string C12345678

This is what I have tried :

```
 elseif(substr($str, 1, preg_match("/^[0-9]/", $str) === FALSE))
     {
       $this -> set_message('is_valid_student_id', 'Must have 8 digits 0 - 9');
       return FALSE;
     }
```

The first character will always be a character the last 8 are always numeric.

Thanks

> Edit 1 :

So doing what you guys told me is not giving me the expected outcome...

```
elseif (preg_match("/^\c\d{8}$/i", $str) === FALSE) // Lower case cC + 8 digits
     {
       $this -> set_message('is_valid_student_id', 'must have 8 digits 0 - 9');
       return FALSE;
     }
```

Is not returning FALSE even if I type in a letter after the first letter [c or C]

Comment: Is it *always* eight digits after the first character? What about a regex like:

/^\D\d{8}$/

Comment: Yes no matter what, it will always be 8 digits after the first letter.

Comment: Your syntax does not look correct, you are passing in preg_match as a third parameter of substr?

Comment: That Regex I gave then should test that's always a single non-digit, followed by eight digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a non-regex solution?

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rzX6OF)**

```
$student_id = "C123b5678";

if(ctype_alpha($student_id[0])){
    if(ctype_digit(substr($student_id,1,strlen($student_id) - 1))){
       echo 'valid';
    }
    else{
       echo 'invalid';
    }

} else { echo 'invalid starting character'; }
// echoes invalid
```

EDIT: As pointed out by Cryode, `is_numeric()` is far too broad for this application. It would allow strings like `C1e5` to pass as valid... Using `ctype_digit()` fixes this issue. If desired, add a check for `strlen()` as well.

Comment: You ever get mad at your self for not doing the easiest least time consuming way? Cause I just did... this was super easy, allowed for a lot of customization when it comes to shooting error messages and works very well! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Every.single.day. :) Glad it helped you out. Happy coding!

Comment: `is_numeric()` is far too broad for this application. For example, using this code, the student ID `C1e5` passes as valid.

Comment: @Cryode you are correct... Didn't even notice that. Updated answer to fix that.

Comment: You can also leave out the third parameter of `substr` if you want to retrieve everything except the first character.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
if (preg_match('~^C[0-9]{8}$~', $str))
    ...true...
else
    ...false...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `if (preg_match('/.\d+/'))`?
The `.` part says "any symbol in length of 1"; the `\d+` is numbers only, one or more occurrences.

Update:
To disallow numbers in the first position, use
`preg_match('/[^\d]\d+/')`.

Comment: The initial `.` would allow for anything which would mean `123456789` and `!123456789` would match

Answer (score 0):

The simplest regex for this would be

```
/^C\d{8}$/
```

which you could use with just `preg_match` so no `sub_str` would be required. Alternatively, if you wanted it to match any letter rather than just a `C` to begin with, you could use

```
/^[a-z]\d{8}$/i
```

This will match both upper and lower case letters at the beginning of the string

Comment: @user2406611 you have a backslash before your c in your edit. Try this `/^C\d{8}$/i`

Comment: I'd vote you up for helping and giving me a better understanding of regex but I am under the points needed

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using `substr()` wrong, in a couple ways. [The third parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is the length of the sub-string you want to return, starting from the position given in the second parameter.

`substr()` will also return false if the function fails, not if there isn't a positive match. For a feature like that, you want [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

You can use `preg_match()` by itself to verify the structure of your short string.

Assuming that:

- The first character will always be a letter
- The remaining characters will always be numbers.

We can use this:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]\d+$/', $str)
```

If your first character should be a capital letter only, you can remove the `a-z` part (or vice versa for lowercase).

If the number digits will be a specific length, you can specify that using `{X}`:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]\d{8}$/', $str) // Exactly 8 numbers
```

Comment: You don't escape the C (no need for the back slash before it).